# Showing that the projection map $\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

I want to show that the projection map $\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto x$ is continuous using the standard metric for $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the standard metric for $\mathbb{R}$

**Proof**

Let $\epsilon>0$, $\delta_{0}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Let $x, y, x_{0}, y_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2}<\delta_{0}$

$$|x-x_{0}|=\sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2}\le\sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2}<\delta_{0}<\epsilon$$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: The spot I would be careful here is the assertion $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2}\le\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$. Why is that true?

Comment: @AshwinTrisal, I would say that it is true because the square root function is increasing and $(y-y_{0})^2$ is non-negative. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @Sadem You are correct.